# ionic 2/angularjs 2 ion-datetime unable to set value in hour

Tags: typescript, ionic2, angular2-routing

I am using ionic 2.1.18 with angularjs 2 RC4 and I got a problem set hour

**booking.html**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Start Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="startDate" min="{{thisYear}}" max="{{nextYearWithLastDay}}"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item> 

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Start Time (Hour)</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH00" [(ngModel)]="startTime" pickerFormat="HH"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

**booking.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-booking',
  templateUrl: 'booking.html'
})
export class Booking {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  now: Date = new Date();
  thisYear : Number = this.now.getFullYear();
  nextYearWithLastDay : String = (this.now.getFullYear() + 1) + "-12-31";

  startDate: String = this.now.toISOString();
  endDate: String = this.now.toISOString();

  startTime: Number = this.now.getHours();
  endTime: Number = this.now.getHours();

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Booking');

  }

}
```

startDate able to set to current date but start time unable to set despite I already define in the class

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I did not test, but set your time like this:

```
startTime = this.now.getHours()+':'+ this.now.getMinutes();
displayFormat="HH:00"
```

Comment: you are setting String to Number and sure failed !

Comment: sorry i just copy you code. see this [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/datetime/basic/pages.ts). i also edit the answer.